# Reactive UI how to use WhenAny using two properties?

Tags: .net, wpf, reactiveui

I am trying to use WhenAny (Reactive UI) for the first time.

When a Identifier =="xyz" and a IsMax field get changes, want to set a local value to true in the subscribe,

```
   this.WhenAny(x => x.IsMax, x => x.Value)
       .Subscribe(x => 
            {
                if (Identifier == "xyz")
                {  
                   isOk = true; 
                }
            });
```

but is there any other way to merge Identifier condition as well?

Comment: if you're property name really is value that could be a problem because it matches with the single value WhenAny() Also consider using WhenAnyValue() and the subscribe will alsol have args ( arg1, arg2 ) => ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ReactiveUI, but if it uses the same IObservable as Reactive Extensions, then you could do this:

```
   this.WhenAny(x => x.IsMax, x => x.Value)
       .Where(_ => Identifier == "xyz")
       .Subscribe(_ => 
           {
               isOk = true;
           });
```

Is this what you wanted?

PS.: I should have asked this in a comment, but I haven't got enough reputation yet.

Comment: You're correct that it should be a comment as it doesn't address the question with ReactiveUI as asked.

Comment: I want to achieve the same using reactive UI.