# ReactiveUI How to add condition using WhenAny?

Tags: .net, wpf-4.0, reactiveui

I'm trying to use `WhenAny` (Reactive UI) for the first time.

When a `Identifier =="xyz"` and a `IsMax` field get changes, want to set a local value to `true` in the `subscribe`.

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.IsMax, x => x.Value).Subscribe(x => 
            {
                if( Identifier =="xyz")
                {  
                   isOk = true; 
                }
            });
```

Is there any other way to merge `Identifier` condition as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reactive UI how to use WhenAny using two properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804765/reactive-ui-how-to-use-whenany-using-two-properties)

Comment: you have `Identifier =="xyz'` Is that a typo in the question or in your actual code?

Comment: try .Where( x => x.Identifier == "xyz" ).Subscribe( ...